# Sitecore - Hierarchical Tagging

Tags: c#, sitecore

I want to tag some pages with a hierarchical object.
For eg:
I have the following tagging options available:

Product Type:
Product 1
Product 2
Product 3

Version:
Version 1
Version 2
Version 3

As a user, I can only access a page which is tagged with the combination of product 2 and version 2 and the combination of product 3 with version 3.

I have 2 pages:
Page 1 which is tagged with Product 2 and version 2 and 
Page 2 tagged with Product 1, Product 2, Version 3, Version 2

Hence, I should only be able to view Page 1. But since there is no linking between product and version, both pages show up.

Is there any way for me to enforce that when I tag the Page with product 1, I can specify that the version type for this product is Version 1? Basically, tag an object Product which has a Product ID and a version ID? Is this something that Sitecore supports or would I have to handle this in my code>

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to do so is to use the Sitecore Rule Engine. This will allows you defined your conditions on hiding the page.

You can check the following link on how to use the Rule Engine https://jeffdarchuk.wordpress.com/2015/06/04/lets-use-that-rules-engine/